# Merging Hash Error

Tags: merge

I'm having issues trying to `merge` a nested hash to get unique values. I'm getting this error which points to the last line of for the loop:

`A hash key must be followed by a colon (:). Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "}" ("punctuation" expected with value ":").`

```
{% set contentTypes = {} %}

{% for row in survey.questions %}
    {% set settings = row.settings.first %}
    {% set factor %}{{ settings.factor }}{{ settings.subFactor ? '_' ~ settings.subFactor }}{% endset %}
    {% set factorLbl = factor|title|replace('_', ' / ') %}
    {% set option %}{{ factor }}: { factorVal: '{{ factor }}', factorLbl: '{{ factorLbl }}'}{% endset %}
    {% set contentTypes = contentTypes|merge({option}) %}
{% endfor %}
```

**Update**

So `factor` is currently being set as a string, which is causing the `merge` to only set the last key in the for loop. How do I concatenate the two strings into a variable if `settings.subFactor` exists?

`{% set factor = settings.factor ~ settings.subFactor ? '_' ~ settings.subFactor %}`

Answer (score 3):

You are setting `option` to a string here:

```
{% set option %}...{% endset %}
```

And [merge](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/merge.html) takes an array or a hash as a parameter. It looks to me like you want `option` to be a hash:

```
{% set option = {factor: {'factorVal': factor, 'factorLbl': factorLbl}} %}
```

Comment: Ahh, good catch. This gets rid of the error, however, the `merge` is not working as it only has one key. Adding  `{{ dump(option) }}` within the `for` loop prints each key. I should have a total of 4 keys within the hash.

Answer (score 0):

Marion got me pointed in the right direction. I was setting `factor` as a string in my original post, which only allowed one key in the hash as it was 'seen' as the same every time through the `merge` function in the for loop. Converting `factor` to a variable fixed this:

```
{% set contentTypes = {} %}

{% for row in survey.questions %}
    {% set settings = row.settings.first %}
    {% set factor = settings.factor ~ (settings.subFactor ? '_' ~ settings.subFactor) %}
    {% set factorLbl = factor|title|replace('_', ' / ') %}
    {% set contentTypes = contentTypes|merge({ (factor) : {'value': factor, 'label': factorLbl} }) %}
{% endfor %}
```